# Scanning a text file

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

it is probably a simple question. I have a problem with scanning a text file. I want to scan a text file and to show the message in a JOptionPane. It scans but it shows only the first line of my text file and then stops disregarding the other lines. If I can get a little help. Thank you very much! Here is my code:

```
File file = new File("src//mytxt.txt");
           try{
               Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
               while(input.hasNext()){
                   String line = input.nextLine();
                   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line);
                   return;        
               }
               input.close();
           }
           catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
               JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
           }
        }
```

Comment: What do you think `return` does and why do you think so?

Comment: If I remove return it shows every new line in a new JOptionPane and I do not want it like that. I want the whole text file to be scanned in one JOptionPane.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using
`while (input.hasNext())
{
    //` `scan` and append each line to a `String` `variable`

}`

`scan` each line from the file and keep the whole text in a `String` variable.
Then use `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,op)` to show the whole text in a single `JOptionPane`.

Comment: Thanks for giving the link @Tom

Answer (score 5):

If you want the whole file to be displayed in a single `JOptionPane`, then create a `StringBuilder` for it, append every line to it and then show it.

```
File file = new File("src//mytxt.txt");
try {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
    StringBuilder op = new StringBuiler();
    while (input.hasNext()) {
        op.append(input.nextLine());
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, op.toString());
    input.close();
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you are displaying only the one line in `JOptionPane`. You have to generate the `message` before displaying it to `JOptionPane` -

```
   File file = new File("src//mytxt.txt");
   String message = "";
   try{
       Scanner input = new Scanner(file);
       while(input.hasNext()){
           String line = input.nextLine();
           message = message+line;       
       }
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, line);
   }
   catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
   }finally{
      input.close();
   }
}
```